# Installing Gitlab CI using Docker for the Ci and the Runners, and make it persistent after reboot

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a server running Gitlab. Let's say that the address is `https://gitlab.mydomain.com`.

Now what I want to achieve is to install a Continuous Integration system. Being that I am using Gitlab, I opt for Gitlab CI, as it feels the more natural way to go. So I go to the Docker repo and I found [this image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/anapsix/gitlab-ci/).

So I run the image to create a container with the following

```
docker run --restart=always -d -p 9000:9000 -e GITLAB_URLS="https://gitlab.mydomain.com" anapsix/gitlab-ci
```

I give it a minute to boot up and I can now access to the CI through the URL `http://gitlab.mydomain.com:9000`. So far so good.

I log in the CI and I am greeted by this message:

```
Now you need Runners to process your builds.
```

So I come back to the Docker Hub and I find [this other image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/sameersbn/gitlab-ci-runner/). Apparently to boot up this image I have to do it interactively. I follow the instructions and it will create configuration files:

```
mkdir -p /opt/gitlab-ci-runner
docker run --name gitlab-ci-runner -it --rm -v /opt/gitlab-ci-runner:/home/gitlab_ci_runner/data sameersbn/gitlab-ci-runner:5.0.0-1 app:setup
```

The interactive setup will ask me for the proper data that it needs:

```
Please enter the gitlab-ci coordinator URL (e.g. http://gitlab-ci.org:3000/ )
http://gitlab.mydomain.com:9000/
Please enter the gitlab-ci token for this runner: 
12345678901234567890
Registering runner with registration token: 12345678901234567890, url: http://gitlab.mydomain.com:9000/.
Runner token: aaaaaabbbbbbcccccccdddddd
Runner registered successfully. Feel free to start it!
```

I go to `http://gitlab.mydomain:9000/admin/runners`, and hooray, the runner appears on stage.

All seems like to work great, but **here comes the problem**:

If I restart the machine, due to an update or whatever reason, the runner is not there anymore. I could maybe add `--restart=always` to the command when I run the image of the runner, but this would be problematic because:

1. The setup is interactive, so the token to register runners have to be input manually
2. Every time the container with Gitlab CI is re-run the token to register new runners is different.

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have a way of pointing you in the right direction but im trying to make it myself, hope we both manage to get it up heres my situation.

im using coreOS + docker trying to do exactly what youre trying to do, and in coreOS you can setup a service that starts the CI everytime you restart the machine (as well as gitlab and the others) my problem is trying to make that same installation automatic.

after some digging i found this: https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/ubergarm/gitlab-ci-runner/

in this documentation they state that they can do it in 2 ways:

- 1-Mount in a .dockercfg file containing credentials into the /root
  directory
- 2-start your container with this info:
- -e CI_SERVER_URL=https://my.ciserver.com \
- -e REGISTRATION_TOKEN=12345678901234567890 \

Meaning you can setup to auto start the CI with your configs, ive been trying this for 2 days if you manage to do it tell me how =(